# Can I install apps to adopted SD card from recovery?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, external-sd, app2sd, bootloader-lock

WhatsApp is [stubborn about not installing to SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150583/is-there-a-way-to-move-unmovable-apps-to-the-sd-card-in-android-6-0). I have an unlocked bootloader, but have not rooted or installed a custom recovery yet. I am trying to avoid rooting because of SafetyNet, and because I need it pretty much only for force-moving WhatsApp (etc.) to an adopted SD card.

Since my bootloader is unlocked, is it not possible to:

- boot into custom recovery without flashing it
- create a flashable .zip containing WhatsApp
- instruct the installer to locate it in adopted storage, ignoring the app's `installLocation` setting

?

Why is it said that we need root for force moving apps, when the bootloader being unlocked should be enough? I don't have a problem with flashing a custom recovery, just ... why flash when one-time boot should be sufficient?

Likely I'm missing some limitations of `fastboot` and the recovery here.

**Edit**: Trying out @DanHalli's answer gave me an error

```
P:\Software\Management\SmartPhone\apks>adb install -s WhatsApp.apk
3644 KB/s (38480037 bytes in 10.311s)
        pkg: /sdcard/tmp/WhatsApp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
```

Comment: I don't know your device and whether it has TWRP available. If so: one-time `fastboot boot twrp.img`, then flash Magisk – et voila: systemless root, passes safetynet (not by hearsay, I did that on one of my devices).

Comment: Thanks for trying my answer, that error usually occurs when there isn't enough storage on the device you're trying to install to, check how much storage is left on the SD card

Answer (score 0):

If you have the APK for WhatsApp on a computer and USB debugging on you can do

`adb install -s path/to/APK`

I might have my syntax wrong, if you have it already installed you might need to add a `-r` after the `-s`  to have it reinstall, I've noticed it works kind of like a force install

Comment: Adoptable storage allows use of a specially formatted (partition on an) SD  Card for use of apps on it : http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/135716-how-to-use-adoptable-storage-on-android-6-0-marshmallow

Comment: Gave an error, check edit.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious... I have 14GB+ free on my adopted partition and 14GB+ free on my portable partition.